# cakephp use another model within model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have two models named `message.php` and `user.php`

In message.php, I have following method that counts #no of messages of verified users.

```
<?php
class Message extends AppModel {
   ...
   ...
   ...
   function getInboxCount($userId) {
      // Here I want to get list of ids of verified users. It means I need to use User model for this. How is it possible?
      // $ids = $this->User->find('list', array('conditions' => array('User.status' => 'verified'))); Will this work?
   }
}
?>
```

So how can I use User model in Message model?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the two models are associated in any way (Message belongsTo User or so), you can access it simply with:

```
$this->User->find(...);
```

If they're not associated, you can import any other model at any time using:

```
$User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
$User->find(...);
```

Comment: This is correct in CakePHP < 2.0, but isn't there another method of doing this in CakePHP >= 2.0?

Comment: you can use the following `$this->loadModel('ModelName');`